# How to instantiate objects during a unit test's setup phase in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, nose

I've been diving into unit testing with Python, but can't figure out how I'm supposed to instantiate the object I want to test during the setup phase, and end up with a new object for each test. 
For example, I have the following class I want to test:

```
class Cfg():
    data = {}

    def set(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value

    def get(self, key):
        return self.data.get(key, None)
```

For each unit test, I want a newly instantiated `Cfg` object. My tests look like this:

```
from cfg import Cfg

class TestCfg():
    def setup(self):
        self.cfg = Cfg()

    def teardown(self):
        self.cfg = None

    def test_a(self):
        self.cfg.set('foo', 'bar')
        assert self.cfg.get('foo') == 'bar'

    def test_b(self):
        assert self.cfg.get('foo') == 'bar'
```

I don't understand why `test_b` passes. I expected `setup` and `tearDown` to 'reset' my `cfg` instance, but it seems that `cfg` is persisting between tests. What am I doing wrong here and how can I achieve the expected behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to how you've written `Cfg` class. Move `data` initialization into `__init__` method:

```
class Cfg():
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {}

    def set(self, key, value):
        self.data[key] = value

    def get(self, key):
        return self.data.get(key, None)
```

And, you'll see failing `test_b`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of the issue being due to the `Cfg` class. This makes total sense.